# Create a model observer that creates an associated model relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following models:

```
User (id,email,name)
Group (id,domain)
GroupUser (id, group_id, user_id)
```

What I would like to do is anytime a user is created. Find the user's email domain and automatically create the Group and the joining GroupUser record.

After performing:

```
u = User.new
u.email = 'bob@ge.com'
u.name = "my name"
```

What is the right way in the user model/observer to make this happen?

Answer (score 1):

You should create a UserObserver `rails g observer UserObserver` and define an action:

```
def after_create(user)
    domain = user.email.split("@").last
    if (group = Group.where(domain: domain)).any?
        GroupUser.create(group.id, user.id)
    else
        group = Group.create(domain)
        GroupUser.create(group.id, user.id)
    end
end
```